# Convert query with JSON_EXTRACT from MySQL to BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have the following query on MySQL:

```
    SELECT COALESCE(
                TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(fb.p_dataforanalytics,'$.gender')),   
                TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM JSON_EXTRACT(g.p_dataforanalytics,'$.gender'))                                                       
                ) as chosen_gender
   FROM ...
```

this works on MySQL but it doesn't work on BigQuery:

> Syntax error: Expected ")" but got string literal '"'

There is some problem with TRIM/JSON_EXTRACT.

How can I do this in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `gender` key points to a single scalar value, then BigQuery's `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` function may be what you need here:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(fb.p_dataforanalytics, "$.gender"),
             JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(g.p_dataforanalytics, "$.gender")) AS chosen_gender
FROM yourTable;
```

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#json_extract_scalar), there should be no need to trim double quotes as they won't appear in the output.